# Woocommerce page title appearing in wrong place

Tags: php, woocommerce

I am having an issue with the page title text appearing outside the h3 tags.

The PHP I am working with is:

```
$pagetitle = woocommerce_page_title();
echo '<h3>' . $pagetitle . '</h3>';
```

This is rendering like this:

```
Shop
<h3></h3>
```

I want it to be like this:

```
<h3>Shop</h3>
```

If I just use:

```
$pagetitle = Shop;
echo '<h3>' . $pagetitle . '</h3>';
```

It works fine. Does anyone know what could be causing this issue?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As per https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/function-woocommerce_page_title.html, the function will echo the title by itself, unless you specify the "echo" parameter as `false`.

This is why you are seeing the title outside the h3 tags - it gets echoed before you output the tags, and in that mode it doesn't return a value.

So you can either do

```
echo '<h3>';
woocommerce_page_title();
echo '</h3>';
```

which will mean woocommerce echoes the title, but in the right place...

Or

```
$pagetitle = woocommerce_page_title(false);
echo '<h3>' . $pagetitle . '</h3>';
```

which tells woocommerce simply to return the title without echoing it.

Comment: *grumble* functions that have echo's inside them *grumble* ;)

Comment: @IncredibleHat yes...not very good functional separation is it :-)

Comment: Its ok if the echos are default OFF, but in this case as you explained... they are defaulted on unless told not too. Personally I just dislike that style of option ;)

Comment: @IncredibleHat agreed, off by default would be good, but really it would be a much more sensible design to just provide a function which returns the value, and let the caller decide what to do with it, instead of this duality. It's a bit confusing at best, even if the documentation does mention it. Luckily I don't have to deal with the evident joy of this particular product, I simply guessed what the problem might be and went and looked it up.